# Trying to add user inputted chatroom name through Ajax and Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax

I just started learning computer science last year and have been struggling despite reading textbooks on the subject. I could not find anywhere regarding sending ajax form data to python and then checking it in a dictionary then parsing it into a json object. Just so confused about it. I know dictionary has key and value pairs, trying to attain user input keys and values...

I tried to address the KeyError codes such as KeyError none, or changing the keys of the dicts but I really don't know where to begin. First code is python, second one is javascript

```
  <div class="modal-content">
    <p>Enter new chatroom name</p>
    <form id="form1">
           <input id="chatroom" autocomplete="off" autofocus placeholder="Name" type="text">
           <input type="submit" class="submit_button" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
```

```py
class chatrooms(dict):
    # __init__ function
    def __init__(self):
        self = dict()
    # Function to add key:value
    def add(self, key, value):
        self[key] = value

chats = chatrooms()

#user to add a new channel
@app.route("/add_chatroom", methods=["POST"])
def create_chatroom():
    # get chatroom name
    chatroom = request.form.get("chatroom")
    # get user name from local storage
    username = request.form.get("username") # isn't this a string

    # if the chatroom does not yet exist
    chats.add(username, chatroom)

    return jsonify({"success": True, "chatroom": chats[username][chatroom]})

    return jsonify({"success": False})
```

```
    document.querySelector('#form1').onsubmit = function() {
        const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const chatroom = document.querySelector('#chatroom').value;
        const username = localStorage.getItem('name');
        request.open('POST', '/add_chatroom');
        // Callback function for when request completes
        request.onload = () => {
            // Extract JSON data from request
            const data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            // Update the result div
            if (data.success) {
                const contents = `${data.chatroom}`
                alert(contents);
            }
            else {
                alert('There was an error.');
            }
        }

        // add data to send to the server
        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('chatroom', chatroom)
        data.append('username', username);

        // Send request
        request.send(data);
        return false;
      };
```

return jsonify({"success": True, "chatroom": chats[username][chatroom]})
TypeError: string indices must be integers

I am getting errors like these, But I am unsure how to key in custom keys for dicts.

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `int`:

```
return jsonify({ "success": True, "chatroom": chats[int(username)][int(chatroom)] })
```